# Returning pure Django form errors in JSON

Tags: django, json, unicode, django-forms, lazy-evaluation

I have a Django form which I'm validating in a normal Django view. I'm trying to figure out how to extract the pure errors (without the HTML formatting). Below is the code I'm using at the moment.

```
return json_response({ 'success' : False,
                       'errors' : form.errors })
```

With this, I get the infamous proxy object error from Django. Forcing each error into Unicode won't do the trick either, because then each of the errors' `__unicode__` method will be called effectively HTML-izing it.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

For those interested, this is the definition of `json_response`:

```
def json_response(x):
    import json
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(x, sort_keys=True, indent=2),
                        content_type='application/json; charset=UTF-8')
```

Comment: The accepted answer is outdated. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28256365/604511

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Got it after a *lot* of messing around, testing different things.  N.B. I'm not sure whether this works with internationalization as well. This also takes the first validation error for each field, but modifying it to get all of the errors should be rather easy.

```
return json_response({ 'success' : False,
                       'errors' : [(k, v[0].__unicode__()) for k, v in form.errors.items()] })
```

Comment: you could also try: `form.error_class.as_text(v)` on `v` (which is an ErrorList), instead of calling `__unicode__()` on each item of `v`

Comment: errors =  dict([(k, form.error_class.as_text(v)) for k, v in form.errors.items()])
return json_response({"errors":errors})

Comment: I found the following to provide a better structure, and also cater for items with more than 1 error: `{k: v for k, v in context['signup_form'].errors.items()}`

Answer (score 37):

This appears to have been improved. The following works in Django 1.3:

```
return json_response({
    'success': False,
    'errors': dict(form.errors.items()),
})
```

No need for `__unicode__` or lazy translation any more. This also gives a full array of errors for each field.

Comment: @digitalPBK care to elaborate?

Comment: I got the same error as when using form.errors, (Some Lazy class) object cannot be serialized.

Comment: doesn't work for me either (django 1.4) ... why is this so highly voted?

Comment: Works in Django dev. I guess it's for 1.5 and higher.

Answer (score 32):

For Django 1.7+ use [Form.errors.as_json()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors.as_json) or something like this:

```
errors = {f: e.get_json_data() for f, e in form.errors.items()}
return json_response(success=False, data=errors)
```

Comment: Updated docs link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors.as_json

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is that error message are lazy translation object. 
The [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/?from=olddocs#id2) do mention this:

Just make sure you've got ensure_ascii=False and use a LazyEncoder.

Comment: That's the way to go. I added an answer which gives some details to this approach.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this:

```
import simplejson as json

errors = json.dumps(form.errors)
return HttpResponse(errors, mimetype='application/json')
```

Answer (score 1):

`json.dumps` can't serialize django's proxy function (like lazy translations).

As [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats-json) you should create a new Encoder class:

```
import json
from django.utils.functional import Promise
from django.utils.encoding import force_text
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

class LazyEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Promise):
            return force_text(obj)
        return super(LazyEncoder, self).default(obj)
```

Use the new Encoder like this:

```
json.dumps(s, cls=LazyEncoder)
```

That's all :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use django in built method.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
return JsonResponse(form.errors.as_json())
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using `get_json_data()` as follows:

```py
data = form.errors.get_json_data()
return JsonResponse(data, status=400, safe=False)
```

We get a valid json:

```json
{"amount": [{"message": "Ensure this value is greater than or equal to 100.", "code": "min_value"}]}
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors.get_json_data

---

If we use `as_json()` like this:

```py
data = form.errors.as_json()
return JsonResponse(data, status=400, safe=False)
```

We get a string formatted as a json:

```json
"{\"amount\": [{\"message\": \"Ensure this value is greater than or equal to 100.\", \"code\": \"min_value\"}]}"
```