# How to serialize dictionary in django to render in Jquery [Level of question - Beginner]

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, json, serialization

The dictionary to serialize -
form.errors

e.g. view -

```
form = PersonalForm(request.POST)
# errors = serializing function which serializes form.errors
data = errors 
#Is this the way to pass data? Not quite sure....
return HttpResponse(data,mimetype="application/json")
```

e.g. javascript (on success of request) -

```
function(responseData) {
     $('#errors_form').html(responseData);
                },
```

Now how do I do this my friends?

Comment: So how can i improve my question?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are asking? What is the problem? What do you expect and what do you see?

Comment: Hey i'm about to delete this question.... I have put up a better version out here, if you can please help..it's driving me mad!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362501/how-to-serialize-dictionary-in-django-to-render-in-jquery-level-of-question-be

Comment: I still don't understand what you are asking. Did you try it? What did you observe? What did you think should happen but did not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986406/returning-pure-django-form-errors-in-json ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import json

data = json.dumps(errors)

return HttpResponse(data,mimetype="application/json")
```

You're asking how to turn a dictionary into a JSON object, so your jQuery/javascript can read it. json.dumps allows this to happen.

Comment: As one "should" search for similar questions before asking, I think one  should also search before answering a question :) Your answer is a sub-optimal duplicate of this one -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986406/returning-pure-django-form-errors-in-json

Comment: So you're saying I should NOT have answered this question because another person answered a similar question? That does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to look in two places for errors.

There are "Non field errors":

```
form.non_field_errors
```

And field based errors, for example the name field:

```
form.name.errors
```

Depending on the complexity of the form, you could reference the errors as individual errors in your json, or make a small python script that combined them. I didn't actually run the code, but think this could work for you:

```
errors = []
errors = errors + form.non_field_errors

for field in form:
    errors = errors + field.errors

if len(errors) > 0 :
    data = json.dumps({"response_text": "Errors Detected", "errors" : errors})
```

Comment: I think you didn't get my question...  the errors itself is not the problem as much as its format...

Answer (score 0):

Not being picky here but did you actually validate your form ?

```
form.is_valid()
```

Comment: @Sussagittikasusa - no, form.errors is not populated until you call is_valid().