# django errors in jQuery (get and show errors)

Tags: jquery, django

I use jQuery(ajax) in django, and I want when happen error in django server i get server error instead `"the server responded with a status of 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)"`
In fact I want to get django error msg (for example "KeyError or model not found and etc." in ajax function

```
$.ajax({
    ...
success:function(json){
    ...
},
error:function(xhr,errmsg,err){

    // this here i want to show django error)
    alert(django error msg);
}
});
```

thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning pure Django form errors in JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986406/returning-pure-django-form-errors-in-json)

Comment: but i dont use form.error happen in views when i try to create new instance of a model:                            'ins = Comment.objects.create(...)'

Comment: where is your view and whole ajax code? That's important for displaying errors in the ajax call.

Comment: Why do you need this? It's generally a bad idea to leak the error details to front end. If think you need it for development - use a debugger and write unit tests instead.

Comment: thank you evryone.my problem is solved.i finaly forced to use try...except